# Performance difference of "if if" vs "if else if"

Tags: c++, c

I was just thinking is there any performance difference between the 2 statements in C/C++:

Case 1:

```
if (p==0)
   do_this();
else if (p==1)
   do_that();
else if (p==2)
   do_these():
```

Case 2:

```
if(p==0)
    do_this();
if(p==1)
    do_that();
if(p==2)
    do_these();
```

Comment: Run a benchmark? (My guess: no, not with any reasonable compiler)

Comment: Running a benchmark is a modern substitute for understanding how things work?

Comment: Not only performance, but the meaning is entirely different! Imagine `p` overloads `operator==` to always return `true`, and `do_that()` sends all your money to your ex wife.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `switch`

Comment: Just worry about writing clear, concise, robust and reliable code - worrying about tiny micro-optimisations such as this is counter-productive and pointless.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker He didn't ask how the things work.  He asked whether there was a performance difference.  And the only way to know the latter is to measure.

Comment: @JamesKanze, no, measurement will highly depend on the data your run the code over.

Comment: @PaulR Though in general you would be right, the question is still a valid and interesting one and it's never pointless to gain more insight into what the computer really does (and neither counter-productive, as long as you don't let such concerns be your major coding guide, which the OP doesn't imply here).

Comment: @KerrekSB had to think of it before marriage ;-)

Comment: If only all the time people spend on bashing "microoptimization" could've been spent on writing clear, concise, robust and reliable code, it would be also "microoptimized".

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker +100 perfect comment.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Obviously, you measure with the data that interests you.  The fact remains that there is no other way of determining performance.

Comment: @JamesKanze, true, since thinking is obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Of course, what do you think we have the computers for? ;)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker No amount of thinking will give you the correct answer.

Comment: @JamesKanze, no amount of testing either. But thinking will give your an *idea*.

Comment: @ChristianRau, for benchmarking? :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Often the wrong idea.  Whereas a well written benchmark will actually give you the facts.

Comment: @JamesKanze, sure wrong thinking will give you the wrong idea. Actually, there's no point in our discussion, I doubt you'll submit to the charms of thinking, nor I am likely to quit this pleasure.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Since you refuse to accept reality, there is no point in continuing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming simple types (in this case, I used `int`) and no funny business (didn't redefine operator= for int), at least with GCC 4.6 on AMD64, there is no difference. The generated code is identical:

```
0000000000000000 <case_1>:                                   0000000000000040 <case_2>:
   0:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi               40:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   2:   74 14                   je     18 <case_1+0x18>        42:   74 14                   je     58 <case_2+0x18>
   4:   83 ff 01                cmp    $0x1,%edi               44:   83 ff 01                cmp    $0x1,%edi
   7:   74 27                   je     30 <case_1+0x30>        47:   74 27                   je     70 <case_2+0x30>
   9:   83 ff 02                cmp    $0x2,%edi               49:   83 ff 02                cmp    $0x2,%edi
   c:   74 12                   je     20 <case_1+0x20>        4c:   74 12                   je     60 <case_2+0x20>
   e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax                 4e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  10:   f3 c3                   repz retq                      50:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
  12:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)        52:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  18:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax               58:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  1a:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1f <case_1+0x1f>        5a:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5f <case_2+0x1f>
  1f:   90                      nop                            5f:   90                      nop
  20:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax               60:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  22:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   27 <case_1+0x27>        62:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   67 <case_2+0x27>
  27:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)        67:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  2e:   00 00                                                  6e:   00 00 
  30:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax               70:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  32:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   37 <case_1+0x37>        72:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   77 <case_2+0x37>
  37:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  3e:   00 00
```

The extra instruction at the end of case_1 is just for [padding (to get the next function aligned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798356/amd64-nopw-assembly-instruction).

This isn't really surprising, figuring out that p isn't changed in that function is fairly basic optimization. If p could be changed (e.g., passed-by-reference or pointer to the various `do_…` functions, or was a reference or pointer itself, so there could be an alias) then the behavior is different, and of course the generated code would be too.

Comment: It is not possible to redefine `operator==` (or `operator=`) for `int` anyway ...

Answer (score 22):

In the former case conditions after the one matched are not evaluated.

Comment: The man speaks the truth. In a worst case scenario, they'll be the same. Otherwise if-else-if will be faster since as soon as one condition is satisfied, the remaining will not be evaluated.

Comment: It's not that I mind, but what could be the possible reason for a downvote here? I run out of ideas.

Comment: @xbonez: Never underestimate compilers... I wouldn't be surprised if both pieces of code ended up with the same assembly (in C, where `==` cannot be overloaded) as the compiler could infer that only one of the conditions can be true (assuming that the *if-branch* does not modify the value being tested) That is, assuming that the result of both versions is the same and types are basic types, the compiler can convert both into a switch.

Comment: Don't overestimate compilers, they don't even know if the code has the same meaning.

Comment: Good point - what if each block is allowed to modify `p`... (and try proving that a pointer to `p` hasn't been stored on a disk somewhere and can be retrieved by those functions).

Comment: @Kerrek: escape-analysis can often prove no such pointer has been stored, although obviously with plenty of cases where in fact it hasn't, but the analysis can't prove it. If the compiler can inline `do_this()` then it can attack the question from the other end, which is why strict aliasing rules matter -- if `p` is an `int` whereas `do_this()` only modifies `float` variables via pointers, the compiler is permitted to assume that `do_this()` doesn't modify `p`.

Comment: Even in C if you marked `p` as `volatile` the compiler would be forced to compile the code quite differently in each case. Or indeed if those functions had memory indicators like fences, etc. Simply put Michael is right, these is a different logical sequence of code. Performance aside, the coder should first determine which is the _correct_ sequence of code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas `==` cannot be overloaded for builtin types in C++ either.

Answer (score 18):

**if else** is **faster**; if a match was found before the last if then at least the last if statement is skipped, if match was found in first it will skip all other statements.

**if if** is **slower**; even if a match was found using the first if statement, it will keep on trying to match in other statement.

Comment: What? The accepted answer, written 2 years before this one, already shows that the compiler realizes that if  `if (p == 0)` is true `p` cannot also have some other value, so those tests are skipped.

Comment: @BoPersson my answer is logical that do not apply to a single specific programming language or hardware as the accepted answer does.

Comment: `if` blocks with returns work the same as if-else.

Comment: I suspect that the language optimizer reads that block and creates a switch statement.

Answer (score 8):

Yes the performance difference is:

The second statement evaluate every IF

Answer (score 5):

As it has already been demonstrated... it varies.

If we are talking about primitive (built-ins) types like `int`, then the compiler may be smart enough so that it does not matter (or not). In any case though, the performance impact will be minor because the cost of calling a function is much higher than that of a `if`, so the difference will probably get lost in the noise if you ever attempt to measure it.

The semantics, however, are quite different.

When I read the first case:

```
if (...) {
  // Branch 1
} else if (...) {
  // Branch 2
}
```

Then I know that no matter what the two branches might do, only one can ever be executed.

However, when I read the second case:

```
if (...) {
}
if (...) {
}
```

Then I have to wonder whether there is a possibility that both branches be taken or not, which mean that I have to scrutinize the code in the first to determine whether it is likely to influence the second test or not. And when I finally conclude it's not, I **curse** the bloody developer who was too lazy to write that damn `else` that would have saved me the last 10 minutes of scrutiny.

So, *help yourself and your future maintainers*, and concentrate on getting the semantics right and clear.

And on this subject, one could argue that perhaps this dispatch logic could be better express with other constructs, such as a `switch` or perhaps a `map<int, void()>` ? (beware of the latter and avoid over-engineering ;) )

Answer (score 3):

You probably won’t notice any difference in performance for such a limited number of expressions. But theoretically, the `if..if..if` requires to check every single expression. If single expressions are mutally exclusive, you can save that evaluation by using `if..else if..` instead. That way only when the previous cases fail, the other expression is checked.

Note that when just checking an int for equality, you could also just use the `switch` statement. That way you can still maintain some level of readability for a long sequence of checks.

```
switch ( p )
{
    case 0:
        do_this();
        break;

    case 1:
        do_that();
        break;

    case 2:
        do_these():
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If..If case could be improved by using a DONE flag in all subsequent IF checks (since true logic is evaluated left-right), to avoid double work/match and optimization.

```
bool bDone = false;

If( <condition> ) {
    <work>;
    bDone = true;
}
if (!bDone && <condition> ) {
    <work>;
    bDone = true;
}
```

Or could use some logic like this:

```
While(true) {
    if( <condition> ) {
        <work>;
        break;
    }
    if( <condition> ) {
        <work>;
        break;
    }
    ....
    break;
}
```

though it's somewhat confusing to read (ask "why do this way")

Answer (score 0):

The major difference is that the if/else construct will stop evaluating the ifs() once one of them returns a true. That means it MAY only execute 1 or 2 of the ifs before bailing. The other version will check all 3 ifs, regardless of the outcome of the others.

So.... if/else has a operational cost of "Up to 3 checks". The if/if/if version has an operational cost of "always does 3 checks". Assuming all 3 of the values being checked are equally likely, the if/else version will have an average of 1.5 ifs performed, while the if/if one will always do 3 ifs. In the long term, you're saving yourself 1.5 ifs worth of CPU time with the "else" construct.

Comment: "always does 3 checks" - unless the optimizer is clever enough to prove to its own satisfaction that the value of `p` doesn't change during `do_this()` or `do_that()`. Then in the if/if case, and assuming no overloaded operators, it could realize that if `p==0` is true then `p==1` can't possibly also be true, and skip evaluating it, just as if the code was if/else. The abstract machine performs 3 checks, but whether the implementation does is another matter.